# Robots.txt block access to all https:// pages

Tags: robots.txt

What would the syntax be to block all access to any bots to https:// pages?  I have an old site that now doesn't have an SSL and I want to block access to all https:// pages

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don’t know if it works, if the robots use/request different `robots.txt` for different protocols. But you could deliver a different `robots.txt` for requests over HTTPS.

So when `http://example.com/robots.txt` is requested, you deliver the normal `robots.txt`. And when `https://example.com/robots.txt` is requested, you deliver the `robots.txt` that disallows everything.

Comment: Any idea how I can easily do this??  I use ISAPI rewrite?? Can I use that to serve different robots.txt??

Comment: I don’t know the ISAPI rewrite syntax very well. But try something like this:
RewriteCond %SERVER_PORT ^433$
RewriteRule ^/robots\.txt$ /robots.txt.https [L]